# How to centre a label on an image in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, uilabel, center

I want to centre a label inside an image that I have created in Xcode. But I can’t seem to find a way to do it. It will be just like a jumbotron, on the upper part of the app. And it will write something inside of it perfectly centred. Is there a way to this?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

- 0)  Place your Label inside the `UIImageView`.
- 1)  Then Ctrl-drag from it to the `UIImageView` and choose: "center horizontally in container".
- 2)  Do the same with "center vertically in container".
- 3)  Then select your label, go to the Attributes Inspector and change the number of lines to 0.